# Разместить пользовательскую документацию на сервере

Tags: база-данных, проектирование, firebird, interbase

Есть сервер на *FireBird*, и клиенты.
На сервере желательно не расшаривать ни одну папку.
Хочу разместить документацию (*.rtf) на сервере, чтобы не разносить ее на каждый клиент. На клиентских приложениях планирую сделать кнопку «открыть документ».

Можно такое как-нибудь сделать?

Можно конечно документ в БД закачать (поле типа `blob`), но нехотелось бы.

Comment: Неплохо наверное обозначить на чем это сделать.. Поставить любой http сервер и зашарить им папку документации например.. по кнопке можно просто открывать листинг с сервера... Можно собрать документацию в ЗИП, и получать так же, или нугет, в общем вариантов то немало..

Comment: Nginx например можно уговорить листинг директорий в XML отдавать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы в блобах сделал. Не хотите в основной базе - сделайте в отдельной. Это самый простой и надежный вариант для вас. Ставить всякое левое стороннее ПО, настраивать веб-сервера - сложно и может мешать вашему серверу БД и делать дырки в безопасности.
Зачем вам другие сервера, когда у вас уже есть прекрасный БД-сервер?

Ну можете свой минисервер на коленке написать, чтобы по сокету файлы отдавал, но зачем все это городить?